# Освобождение памяти от промежуточного массива

Tags: c++, указатели

как правильно освободить память от промежуточного массива?
например, пусть есть следующий метод:

```
void Calc(int** & A)
{
    int * B = new int[_countI * _countJ];

    /*какие-то вычисления с участием массива B*/

    /*перевод одномерного массива B в двумерный массив A*/
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < _countI; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < _countJ; j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = B[k];
            k++;            
        }
    }
}
```

как далее в этом методе мне освободить память от массива B? если я напишу `delete[] B;`, то что будет с массивом A?

Comment: B c А не связаны в данному случае, удалится B, на А не повлияет (при условии что внизу вы в А не присваеваете B.)

Comment: @nick_n_a, ну вот при переводе элементов массива В в массив А, разве нет связи этих массивов между собой?

Comment: Приведите код, который вы называете "переводом"

Comment: @nick_n_a, дополнил содержание вопроса

Comment: @Naf, в A будут копии объектов из B. Им ничего не угрожает

Comment: почему бы не использовать вектор (http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) и не забивать себе голову, как освобождать временную память?

Comment: `int** & A` за такое надо пороть!

Comment: @alexolut Да ладно, одно лишнее разыменование...:) Другое дело, Naf, что вообще в С++ использовать raw array - несколько нонсенс. Лучше использовать вектора...

Comment: все дело в том, что я правлю чужой код, и тут везде используются именно указатели((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно - удалить массив B оператором delete[] (как вы и собирались). Массив B удалится, а А - нет. Данные, сохраненные в нем останутся.

Comment: С учетом приведенного кода, ответ остается в силе. Вы скопировали значения, так что массив A никак не пострадает при удалении B.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно нет смысла гонять данные туда-сюда между двумерным и одномерными массивами. Гораздо эффективнее использовать функцию перевода пары "строка, столбец" в линейный индекс и наоборот.

Например, все вычисления, которые сейчас делаются с одномерным массивом через индекс `k`, можно было бы выполнять с двумерным массивом, заменив один индекс на пару `i = k / длина_строки`, `j = k % длина_строки`.